# Adding a second time frame selection

Tags: time, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create an indicator where time frames are selectable.
Everything is working except I cannot pick a second time frame on inputs.
this is the code:

The base of this code was created by PasqualeAntonino.
I have simply modified the appearance and added a Moving Average.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="DeMarker", shorttitle="DeM", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="",    timeframe_gaps=true)

len1 = input.int(14, title="Demarker Length")
len0 = input.int(14, title="Demarker Length2")
demax = high > high[1] ? high - high[1] : 0   
demax1 = high > high[1] ? high - high[1] : 0   
demin = low < low[1] ? low[1] - low : 0
demin1 = low < low[1] ? low[1] - low : 0
demax_av = ta.sma(demax, len1)
demax_av1 = ta.sma(demax1, len0)
demin_av = ta.sma(demin, len1)
demin_av1 = ta.sma(demin1, len0)
dmark = demax_av / (demax_av + demin_av)
dmark2 = demax_av1 / (demax_av1 + demin_av1)
len2 = input.int(21, title="Moving Average Length")
len3 = input.int(21, title="Moving Average Length2")
dma = ta.ema(dmark, len2)
dma2 = ta.ema(dmark, len3)

//Plots
h1 = hline(0.7, linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.new(#ef5350, 20), title="Upper Line")
h2 = hline(0.5, linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.new(#787b86, 50), title="Center Line")
h3 = hline(0.3, linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.new(#26a69a, 20), title="Lower Line")
fill(h1, h3, color=color.new(#787b86, 90), title="Background")
plot(dma, color=#787b86, linewidth=1, title="Moving Average 1")
plot(dma2, color=#787b86, linewidth=1, title="Moving Average 2")
plot(dmark, color=#2962ff, linewidth=2, title="Demarker")
plot(dmark2, color=#2962ff, linewidth=2, title="Demarker2")``
```

What should I add to have a second time frame selectable on inpts?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *f_secureSecurity* function from [the PineCoders library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/)

Comment: Really noob here, I just used some code already available to create 2 inputs for the same, but the page you sent me its to avoid non repainting, not doubting your level of expertise, but Are you sure ? I mean what I want is the 2nd indicator line and moving average to be shown on a diferent time frame

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Use the *f_secureSecurity* function

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to start now a new world of discovery, I have no idea where to use it but I will investigate

Comment: I used this:
 i_htf = input.timeframe ('', 'Select Higher Timeframe')
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) =>
    request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

Comment: But still cannot select different components, something is wrong and I cant figure out what but to me it seems I need to separate parameters to use on one time frame and the other, using this what I can see is one extra input for a second time frame but doesnt change anything

Comment: Is there a way to declare this function just for indicator and moving average number 2 for instance ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you should use the function *f_secureSecurity* and moving average

```
//@version=5
indicator('ma Htf', overlay = true)

i_ma  = input.int (21, 'ma')
i_htf = input.timeframe ('','Select Higher Timeframe')

// @function           To securely and simply call `security()` so that it never repaints and never looks ahead.
// @param _symbol      (string) Symbol Ticker ID (syminfo.tickerid).
// @param _res         (string) Higher timeframe used for security() calls.
// @param _src         (string) Source used in security() calls.
// @returns             Data Higher timeframe (No Repaint).
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) =>
    request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

maHtf = f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, i_htf, ta.ema(close, i_ma))
plot(maHtf)
```

Comment: This should probably be merged into the previous answer by you and this post deleted.